# Redis getting “\” to JSON string

Tags: json, redis

I am using Redis to save a value of a JSON and retrieve it later. The problem is when i retrieve the value from the redis, it adds multiple "\" and that ruins my JSON.

```
{ "user": "123456", "password": "xxxxxxx" }

client.lrange('message', 0, -1, function (error, items) {
 if (error) throw error
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    message: items
  }),
 };
 callback(null, response);
})
```

and when i retrieve the value it comes out:

```
{ \"user\": \"123456\", \"password\": \"xxxxxxx\" }
```

Comment: Add details. With a desired and actual output your question will look better.

Comment: I added code and output josn object.

Comment: How are you getting this output? The escaped quotes are the work of the client you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `JSON.stringify` on your the  response returned from your Redis `LRANGE`. Though you'd like this command to return  a list of JSON objects - for Redis it's a list of strings and that's what your code gets. `stringify` causes the double quouting because you never ran `JSON.parse` on top of the strings inside the array to begin with.